# Как распарсить строку-URL в JSON?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Я формирую URL для вызова REST-API.

```
var params = {
    maxResults: 100,
    callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK',
    access_token: self.accessToken
};

var url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/plus/' + self.apiVersion + '/people/' + source.id + '/activities/public?' + $httpParamSerializer(params);
```

После первого вызова, мне нужно добавить к URL параметр `nextPageToken`. В принципе, это можно сделать простой конкатенацией строк, но проблема в том, что в дальнейшем мне придется изменять значение параметра `nextPageToken`, а в конечном итоге вообще передать URL в другую функцию и использовать ее там.

Вопрос - как изменить этот параметр?

Answer (score 1):

Ваша программа, это живой организм, который должен быть разбит на части, объединен по функциональности и управляться одним единственным контроллером - мозгом.

Когда Вам хочется кушать, то желудок не лезет в мозг и не дергает за рычаг включающий соответствующий механизм заставляющий нас бежать к холодильнику. И то что распахнув холодильник Ваши глаза начнут жадно искать жаренное мясо, а не пирожное, не означает что органы, нуждающиеся в белке, неистово толкаясь и перепрыгивая друг через друга карабкаются по позвоночнику вверх, чтобы взять управление над Вами, в головном центре, называемого черепом.

В нашем организме есть механизм, который позволяет органам сообщать их желания в мозг. те же механизмы должны быть и у Вас в программе.

Если вдруг пользователь поставил какую-то галочку в форме, то это не говорит о том что форма или чекбокс должен знать о том что он сейчас будет редактировать строку запроса. Его задача установить свое последнее состояние специально созданной для этого службе. Например, пусть это будет "сервис главного поискового запроса" -

```
class MainRequestService {
  constructor( data ){}
}
```

Объект `data` это объект представляющий сам запрос, он будет содержать нужные нам поля -

```
const mainRequestData = {
  url: "google.com",
  route: "/",
  value: ""
};
```

И вот теперь чтобы Ваши части могли устанавливать значения не зная в принципе о существовании какого-то запроса, наделим наш сервис логикой -

```
class MainRequestDataService {
  constructor( data ){}

  setUrl( value ){}
  setRoute( value ){}
  setValue( value ){}

  getData(){}
}
```

Ход мыслей привел меня к тому, что все запросы абсолютно одинаковые, у них есть `url`, `params`, `headers` и т.п. Поэтому не будет страшно, если я начну рассуждать в сторону универсальности.

Наши данные для запроса должны быть преобразованы к конечному, заранее определенному виду, а значит мы должны создать класс-контейнер под конечный результат -

```
class Request {
    constructor(  ){
        this.url = null;
        this.route = null;
        this.method = null;

    }
}
```

Теперь нам нужно создать класс, который будет адаптировать наши данные под конечный результат. Работенка ещё та, поэтому не обойтись без `Builder` -

```
class Builder {
    create(){}

    createUrl(){}
    createRoute(){}
    createParams(){}
}
```

Метод `create` будет создавать новый экземпляр `Request`, а остальные будут создавать конечные данные и добавлять их в созданный ранее запрос.

Вы могли заметить что в наших данных есть лишь доменный адрес и отсутствует протокол. Я специально так сделал чтобы показать дальнейшую иерархию наших `Builder` -

```
class HttpBuilder {
    constructor(){
        this.data = null;
        this.request = null;

        this.protocol = "http://";
    }
    create(){
        this.request = new Request();
        this.data = MainRequestService.getData();
    }

    createUrl(){
        this.request.url = this.protocol + this.data.domain;
    }
    createRoute(){}
    createParams(){}

    getProduct(){
        return this.request;
    }
}
class HttpsBuilder {
    constructor(){
        this.data = null;
        this.request = null;

        this.protocol = "https://";
    }
    create(){
        this.request = new Request();
        this.data = MainRequestService.getData();
    }

    createUrl(){
        this.request.url = this.protocol + this.data.domain;
    }
    createRoute(){}
    createParams(){}

    getProduct(){
        return this.request;
    }
}
```

Теперь чтобы управлять нашими строителями создадим надсмотрщика с хлыстом `Director` -

```
class Director {
    setBuilder( builder ){

    }

    build(){
        this.builder.create()
        this.builder.createUrl()
        this.builder.createRoute()
        this.builder.createParams()
    }

    getRequest(){
        return this.builder.getProduct();
    }
}
```

На этом все, конструктор запросов готов. Чтобы собрать в голове то, что было написано выше, представьте реальный мир, где Вы **верховный пользователь** создаете рабочего под каждый профиль работ `Builder`. в реальности есть каменщик, плотник, просторабочий. `Builder` содержит только данные и логику их преобразования, сами они ничего не делают, ими руководит `Director` задавая точный план работ и получая готовый продукт.  И в то время как `Director` полностью руководит созданием продукта, он ничего не знает о том что происходит внутри. Именно это позволяет без лишних нервов менять рабочих которые пишутся под каждый конкретный запрос.

Да, под каждый запрос писать своего рабочего! Очень часто бывает что запрос нужно получить в одном месте и предварительно преобразовать его или конвертировать данные. И именно 'Builder` и является этим единым местом.

Те от кого зависит результат запроса должны иметь ссылку на сервис `MainRequestService` чтобы в любой момент установить нужное значение. Далее Вы создаете провайдера, который будет заниматься координированием всех операций -

```
class MainRequestProvider {
    get(){
        MainRequestBuilder.setData( MainRequestDataService.getData() );
        DirectorService.setBuilder( MainRequestBuilder );

        let result = DirectorService.getRequest();

        return result;
    }
}
```

Когда Вам нужно будет сделать запрос, то Вы не задумываясь берете создаете провайдера и передаете его в загрузчик. И не думает что и кто делает.

И лично я в самом начале своего пути был очень педантичен и от того придирчив к архитектуре и только поэтому ещё раз хочу сделать акцент на том, что все запросы создаются по одному правилу. У всех есть адрес, у всех есть заголовки, параметры, данные которые нужно передать. Все это может уложится в несколько интерфейсных методов, например как те, которые первыми пришли в мне голову. В то же время формирование саого адреса может быть разбита на множество ступеней-методов, которые могут быть записанны в самом строителе или же вынесены в отдельный класс или утилсы. Самое главное чтобы запускались они в методе `createURL`, то есть это реально рабочий метод призванный логически отделить создание урла.

Ещё добавлю что я все пишу в классах только потому, что мне кажется что их легче воспринимать. Лично я пишу классы только тогда, когда нужно сохранять промежуточные значения. Если Вы считаете их слишком громоздкими, то пишите так как Вам нравится, главное соблюдение принципов шаблона проектирования [Строитель](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)).

Comment: Замечательный, прекрасный, изумительный и подробный ответ. Только боюсь, он спрашивающему не поможет.